# HERE maps API startPlayback does not work

Tags: java, android

i'm using latest HERE map SDK for Android and wanted to simulate driving by using GPX file saved previously. I did find an api `PositionSimulator.startPlayback`, but when i call it nothing happens. `startPlayback("file_name.gpx")` returns `PlaybackError` object with the value "NONE", so i assume the call did succeed. Does anyone know what could be possible reason for to not to run ?

I'd really appreciate any advice on how to use this API. Thanks.

Comment: why i got a downvote, is there anything wrong about my question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually i found the issue and it ridiculous, the coordinates from GPX file were all the same, that's the reason why it didn't move anywhere.